# SQL command in stored procedure continue on error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dbcc-checkdb

To perform Checkdb on all database of server i am using a stored procedure which loops over a view which contains list of databases in server and the stored procedure performs checkdb on all databases in the server. But if any database has any error(like corrupt etc) then checkdb does not continue to check other database and stops by giving error. But i want checkdb to continue analysing other databases on error. How it can be done?

Below is stored procedure i used.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CHECKDB] AS              

SET NOCOUNT ON              

DECLARE             
    @dbName VARCHAR(255),           
    @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)           

DECLARE sDatabases CURSOR FAST_FORWARD              
  FOR SELECT MP.DatabaseName FROM dbo.DatabaseList MP               
  OPEN sDatabases               
    FETCH sDatabases INTO @dbName               
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0              
    BEGIN           
      SET @dbName = RTRIM(@dbName)          
      PRINT CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + '***************' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 121) +            
                ':  PERFORMING DBCC CHECKS FOR DATABASE [' + @dbName + ']' + '***************' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)
      SET @strSQL = N'DBCC CHECKDB('''+@dbName+''') WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS'            
      EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL            
    FETCH sDatabases INTO @dbName           
    END         
CLOSE sDatabases                
DEALLOCATE sDatabases               


GO
```

Below is a view(DatabaseList ) which is used by stored procedure

```
USE [master]
GO

create VIEW [dbo].[DatabaseList]
AS SELECT
      [name] AS DatabaseName,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [name]) AS DatabaseRank

    FROM sys.databases SDB
        WHERE
      --Exclude system databases
      SDB.[name] NOT IN('tempdb')

GO
```

Comment: I`m guessing you could use a `TRY..CATCH` block.

Comment: Yes...Worked fine. Try catch helped me to solve this problem. If you post it as answer then i can accept it as answer.